# Is there a way to add a column into an existing view in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, view

For a table I can do like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name  
ADD column_name datatype
```

but this does not apply to an existing view. I wonder if there is a way to solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the Alter View statement to edit a view.  Simply use the existing SQL Statement in the current view, and add the column to the end.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-view.html

More detailed explanation than the actual docs can be found here:

http://www.roseindia.net/mysql/mysql5/views.shtml

*Edit - added*

A view can only display data from an existing table.  You would have to add the column to the table and then modify the view to show it as well.

Think of it this way: A view is just a way of looking at existing data in tables.  Tables are holders of real data.

The only exception to the pattern above that I can think of is that you can have a column on a view that is filled with the results of a calculation such as addition or string contention.  For example, consider a table with EmployeeId, FirstName and LastName columns...

You could have a view that looks like this:

```
Create View FullNames AS
Select EmployeeId, firstname + ' ' + lastname AS FullName from Employees
```

In that case, I'm *sort of* adding a column that doesn't exist in a table - FullName.  It's a computed value based on table data.  However, it's still based on data stored in teh DB somewhere.

Comment: I understand how they add a column into an existing view, but they use "select" statement, which means that column has to be from some other tables. What i mean is can I create a brand new column inside view just as the alter table statement does to a table?

Comment: I was also looking for a way to add a column to a view (supposing that the column already exists in the underlying table). I didn't think it was possible though since it doesn't really make sense once you start having views based on complex joins and such.